# Missing Perl modules install from zip

Tags: windows, perl, module

Reinstalling Perl again and checking the missing modules were as follows:

```
D:\circos\bin>perl circos -moduless

ok       1.50 Carp

ok       0.45 Clone

missing            Config::General

ok       3.78 Cwd
```

Downloaded them but need to figure out where to unzip them.
Using "install Config::General" is not the answer I look for.

Comment: Which Perl installation do you use? What is the output of running `perl --version` from CMD ?

Comment: Why isn't `cpan` the answer you are looking for?

Comment: No idea just figured I needed to know how to install the module directly from the download folder without internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [README file](https://metacpan.org/source/TLINDEN/Config-General-2.63/README) that comes with [Config::General](https://metacpan.org/release/TLINDEN/Config-General-2.63). It includes this section:

```
INSTALLATION

    to install, type:
      perl Makefile.PL
      make
      make test
      make install

    to read the complete documentation, type:
    perldoc Config::General
    perldoc Config::General::Extended
    perldoc Config::General::Interpolated

    see some example config files which can
    be parsed with Config::Genreal in the subdirectory
    t/cfg.*
```

Alternatively, Perl includes a [perlmodinstall](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodinstall) manual page which goes into great detail about the various ways to install Perl modules.